# C++ pointer/for-loop confusion

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, for-loop, stdio

I'm trying to write a program that reads values from cin using a pointer, and then outputs the values alongside their position in the array. I can't figure out why printNumbers1 works but printNumbers2 doesn't. Here is the program (relevant code near the bottom):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *readNumbers(int);
void printNumbers1(int*);
void printNumbers2(int*);

int main()
{
    int *numbers = readNumbers(5);
    printNumbers1(numbers);
    printNumbers2(numbers);
    return 0;
}

int *readNumbers(int n)
{
    int a[n];
    int *numbers;
    numbers = &a[0];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin >> *(numbers+i);
    }

    return numbers;
}

void printNumbers1(int *numbers)
{
    cout << 0 << ' ' << *(numbers) << endl
         << 1 << ' ' << *(numbers+1) << endl
         << 2 << ' ' << *(numbers+2) << endl
         << 3 << ' ' << *(numbers+3) << endl
         << 4 << ' ' << *(numbers+4) << endl;
}

void printNumbers2(int *numbers)
{
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout << i << ' ' << *(numbers+i) << endl;
    }
}
```

When I run the program, it works as intended for printNumbers1 but outputs a combination of seemingly random numbers and 0s for printNumbers2. I feel like the two printNumbers functions should should function identically, but they don't. What am I missing?

Comment: `a` is a local variable. It will go out of scope and become invalid at the end of the function. Returning a pointer to it is a bad idea because the pointer will be pointing to bad memory. Your are likely going to have to use `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of a combination of two things:

- **C++ does not allow variable-length arrays** - this is a popular extension, but the declaration `int a[n]` is not standard.
- **You cannot return a pointer to local variable from a function** - pointer `numbers` inside `readNumbers` points to `a`, a local variable. You can use this pointer inside the function, but outside of the function it becomes invalid, because `a` goes out of scope.

Using an out-of-scope variable causes *undefined behavior*. [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/335858) provides a very good explanation of what is happening, and why it may look like the program is working fine.

If you want to use built-in pointers, remove `int a[n]`, and change the declaration of `numbers` as follows:

```
int *numbers = new int[n];
```

You also need to add

```
delete[] numbers;
```

before `return 0` line to avoid memory leaks.

I am assuming that you wrote this code as part of a learning exercise. In general, though, a better approach in C++ is to use `std::vector<int>`, which hides pointer operations from your code, and deals with resource management for you.

Comment: Thanks! The only thing I'm still confused about is why `printNumbers1` works if `a` is out of scope for functions other than `readNumbers`.

Comment: @MemelordSupreme If an array is out of scope, it does not mean it has random garbage: it could have the stuff that you put there before, so, unfortunately, incorrect code may give an appearance of working. However, it's not really working, it's just a situation when random garbage happens to match what you expected to see.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Please add a note about undefined behavior; that's what's causing seemingly-correct behavior.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Done.

Answer (score 1):

readNumbers returns a pointer to a variable with automatic storage duration.

The behaviour on dereferencing that pointer is undefined.

Use a std::vector instead. Rely on return value optimisation to obviate any superfluous value copies being taken.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have created the array a[n] inside the function, so it is a local variable, Hence this array may or may not be deleted after the scope of the function ends.Never use the address of a local variable outside the funcrtion. This code is working:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *readNumbers(int);
void printNumbers1(int*);
void printNumbers2(int*);

int main()
{
    int *numbers = readNumbers(5);
    printNumbers1(numbers);
    printNumbers2(numbers);
    return 0;
}

int *numbers;

int *readNumbers(int n)
{

    numbers = new int[n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
         cin >> *(numbers+i);
    }

    return numbers;
}

void printNumbers1(int *numbers)
{ 
cout << 0 << ' ' << *(numbers) << endl
     << 1 << ' ' << *(numbers+1) << endl
     << 2 << ' ' << *(numbers+2) << endl
     << 3 << ' ' << *(numbers+3) << endl
     << 4 << ' ' << *(numbers+4) << endl;
}

void printNumbers2(int *numbers)
{
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    cout << i << ' ' << *(numbers+i) << endl;
}
}
```